# In IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, can you generate a dependency tree for Maven projects?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition, can you generate a visual diagram of dependency tree for Maven projects?

---

IntelliJ IDEA 2023.3.6 (Community Edition)
Build #IC-233.15026.9, built on March 21, 2024
Runtime version: 17.0.10+1-b1087.23 amd64

Comment: It does not matter you have the community version or not dependency tree can be generated using maven command: "mvn dependency:tree" <- use this command in cmd in  your project directory or click on the execute maven goal in intellij idea and paste this command you will get desired output